# Catching the query results executed in the remote PostGreSQL server through expect command inside Python script

Tags: python, expect, postgresql

I want to catch the **PostGres** query results that gets executed in the remote server (passwordless-ssh) via **expect** command that is used to supply the password for the given PostGres user.
Actually, there are two versions of our application, the older version does not require Postgres password where as the new version requires it. So the Testcase has to handle that

In older version (which does not require psql password) the cmd string to execute the query is very simple:

```
cmd = 'ssh ' + db_ip + ' "psql -h localhost -p 5434 -U perfmon -d network -c \\\"select count(*) from crm_customer_device_info;\\\""'
```

But for the new version (since password is enabled for psql), I have tried the following approaches, but timeout occurs

Approach 1: *executing the query when the prompt appears*

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    _output, _error = proc.communicate()
    _code = proc.returncode
    return _output, _error, _code

def executeQuery(db_ip, db_user, db_name, db_pass, sql_query):
    cmd = '''/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn -noecho ssh -q {0} "psql -h localhost -p 5434 -U {1} -d {2}"
           expect {{
             -nocase "Password*" {{
                send "{3}\r"
                exp_continue
             }}
             "=# " {{
                send "{4}"
                set var $expect_out(buffer);
                send "\q\n"
              }}
           }}
           '
       '''.format(db_ip, db_user, db_name, db_pass, sql_query)
    return execute(cmd)

db_ip = "192.168.0.1"
db_user = "perfmon"
db_name = "network"
db_pass = "xxx"
sql_query = "select count(*) from crm_customer_device_info;"

_output, _error, return_code = executeQuery(db_ip, db_user, db_name, db_pass, sql_query)
```

Approach-2: *executing the query using* **postgres -c** *option and handling timeout scenarios*

```
def executeQuery(db_ip, db_user, db_name, db_pass, sql_query):
    cmd = '''/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh {o} "psql -h localhost -p 5434 -U {1} -d {2} -c \\\'{4}\\\' "
           expect {{
             -nocase "Password*" {{
                send -- "{3}\r"
                exp_continue
             }}
             -nocase "permission denied" {{
               exit 4
             }}
             -nocase "timed out" {{
               exit 2
             }}
             timeout {{
               exit 1
             }}
           }}
           '
       '''.format(db_ip, db_user, db_name, db_pass, sql_query)
    return execute(cmd)
```

When I execute the below **expect** script directly on the server where psql is installed instead of remote ssh, then I manage to get output:

```
spawn -noecho psql -h localhost -p 5434 -U user -d db;
               expect {
                 "^Password*" {
                   send -- "passwd\r"
                   exp_continue
                }
                "*=# " {
                send -- "select now();\r\n"
                set var $expect_out(buffer);

                send "\\q\r\n"
                exp_continue
               }
               }; #puts $var; #interact;
```

Comment: You should consider replacing the use of tcl expect by the python `pexpect` package that provides a basic version of the same functionality. This will help for future maintenance. `pexpect` has a `pxssh` module to automate the ssh login, but personally, I prefer not to use it as it can hide problems that you might want to handle, and it is not useful for passwordless login.